# How to show first 2 characters and replace all the last by *

Tags: javascript, string

I'm wondering how to show the first two characters and replace all last character of a string by symbol *.

**Ex: 121,121,121 -> 12x,xxx,xxx .**

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love using regex when it comes to replace string according to some pattern.

```js
var p = '121,121,121';
var regex = /(?<=.{2})([0-9])/gm;
console.log(p.replace(regex, 'x'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring` and regular expression. See the sample below.

```
var str = "121,121,121";
var res = str.substring(0, 2) + '' +  str.substring(2, str.length).replace(/[0-9]/g,"x");
alert(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `substring` and `replace` with a simple regex (to single out digits and keep commas and other punctuation):

```js
const str = "121,121,121";
const obfuscated = `${str.substring(0, 2)}${str.substring(2).replace(/\d/g, "*")}`;
console.log(obfuscated);
```